How is a state defined in the US constitution?
I am aware that the states originally were legal inheritors of the 13 colonies, Texas was a Republic, and many states were carved out of sold, ceded, even conquered lands. By the Republican form of government clause, it is clear each state has a government, they are not that government. Yet the 17th amendment makes clear each state has a people of the state, implying they are not to be equated with the people. States can also cede land, implying something like ownership of the land. If it is not a government, nor a people, nor a land, what exactly is this thing called a "state"? It seems a tad abstract to my mind.
I would like to know, as I am sure this played a key role in the lead up to the American Civil War, which has always interested me. I believe more people fought for the Union than against slavery in the North, and states' rights as a theory was crucial in justifying slavery-motivated secession in an honor-based antebellum South.

"State's rights" would also be an issue for non-slavery states -- the complicated political history of the U.S. in the decades prior to the Civil War was frought with Southern interests trying to force legal support for slaveholding on states that opposed it. In short, when they couldn't win politically they resorted to violence.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Politics.SE site. The concepts raised in the body of the question are not questions meaningfully related to law and hint that this is really a question about political theory and history.

A State is a sovereign entity admitted into the Union. The Constitution doesn't define the initial States, but defines the process of admission (Article 4). The original 13 States were defined explicitly in the Articles of Confederation, which preceded to the current Constitution:

perpetual Union between the States of Newhampshire, Massachusetts-bay, Rhodeisland and Providence Plantations, Connecticut, New York, New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, Maryland, Virginia, North Carolina, South Carolina, and Georgia

Note the word "perpetual", which is one of the words that played an important part in the conflict leading to the Civil War.

Another way of considering the original 13 States are those which ratified the Constitution after it had been sent to them by the Congress of the Confederation. (Rhode Island had to be coerced into doing so.)

You seem to have a tidy answer, but might I ask for clarification? Why then does the 17th amendment make a distinction between the people and the state. The people are the sovereign. If you give an equally tidy answer, I will accept your answer.

I'm not sure I understand the relationship you're trying to draw here. The people are sovereign as the electorate, if that's what you mean, not as each individual person being a king of their own little kingdom.

The state is the sovereign, and the people are sovereign. Therefore, the people are the state, therefore the state cannot possess a people. It makes no grammatical sense, like "the land of the land".

@gbmye I suspect you're trying to say something you heard someone talk about on Youtube to justify being a criminal. Usually, "sovereign people" claims are raised when people are trying to avoid criminal responsibility. Many times it is raised in context of tax evasion or financial crimes in an attempt to claim that the government cannot dictate "sovereign citizens" what they can do with their money. Bottom line: an individual person is sovereign if and only if they're a monarch. Charles III for example. Not a random US citizen.

Not at all what I mean. 51% of the population = the people.

@gbmye again, no. The people are not some people, it's all people. 100% of the population.

Then how could anyone claim to act for the people with such a high bar? Not even the constitution itself set that bar.

In a democratic Republic elected officials represent all the people, not just those who personally voted for them. Which is exactly the point of the 17th amendment.

Ok I understand. Here is a legal paper that supports your view. https://harvardlawreview.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/vol126_the_people_in_the_constitution.pdf


It seems a tad abstract....

It is indeed abstract.  The most relevant definitions from Johnson's 1755 dictionary are (with selected citations; follow the link for the full entry):


The community; the publick; the commonwealth.

I hear her talk of state matters and the senate. Ben. Johns.
The state hath given you licence to stay on land for the space of six weeks. Bacon.



A republick; a government not monarchical.

They feared nothing from a state so narrow in compass of land, and so weak, that the strength of their armies has ever been made up of foreign troops. Temple.

To arrive at a more specific definition of "state" in the context of the US Constitution, one can refer to the Declaration of Independence, which styles itself "The unanimous Declaration of the thirteen united States of America," the actual declaration being

We, therefore, the Representatives of the united States of America, in General Congress, Assembled, appealing to the Supreme Judge of the world for the rectitude of our intentions, do, in the Name, and by Authority of the good People of these Colonies, solemnly publish and declare, That these United Colonies are, and of Right ought to be Free and Independent States; ... and that as Free and Independent States, they have full Power to levy War, conclude Peace, contract Alliances, establish Commerce, and to do all other Acts and Things which Independent States may of right do.

(Emphasis added)
The text of the Articles of Confederation is furthermore consistent with this:

To all to whom these Presents shall come, we, the undersigned Delegates of the States affixed to our Names send greeting. Whereas the Delegates of the United States of America in Congress assembled did on the fifteenth day of November in the year of our Lord One Thousand Seven Hundred and Seventy seven, and in the Second Year of the Independence of America agree to certain articles of Confederation and perpetual Union between the States of Newhampshire, Massachusetts-bay, Rhodeisland and Providence Plantations, Connecticut, New York, New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, Maryland, Virginia, North Carolina, South Carolina, and Georgia in the Words following, viz. “Articles of Confederation and perpetual Union between the States of Newhampshire, Massachusetts-bay, Rhodeisland and Providence Plantations, Connecticut, New York, New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, Maryland, Virginia, North Carolina, South Carolina, and Georgia.
Article I. The Stile of this confederacy shall be, “The United States of America.”
Article II. Each state retains its sovereignty, freedom and independence, and every Power, Jurisdiction and right, which is not by this confederation expressly delegated to the United States, in Congress assembled.
...

Here, as others have said with respect to the constitution, the definition of state may be seen as  basically equivalent to "the named entities."
In short, "state" originally meant essentially the same as "independent country" in modern English, but it came to have a different connotation as the newly independent countries of North America formed am increasingly tightly bound federation through the Continental Congress, the Articles of Confederation, and the Constitution.  Nobody thought to define "state" explicitly because it was clear from the context what it meant.

The Constitution doesn't provide its own definition of "state", so its meaning is simply the common understanding of the term. Here is the definition given in my MacOS dictionary:

an organized political community or area forming part of a federal republic: the German state of Bavaria.

This seems quite consistent with how we still use the term to refer to the individual states within the USA, so I think it reflects the founders' understanding when they wrote the Constitution. They defined the country as a republic, and it consists of a number of member states. The states operate somewhat independently, but they're also subject to federal principles and send representatives to the federal government.
